# Blender rig will not bend properly

Tags: mesh, armature, bones

I created a torso for a character to rig, made the bones, and parented it. When I rotate the entire leg, it works out good.

[image]

But if I attempt to move the knee, it bends the entire leg and the bones are left exposed.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It looks like you don't have any geometry to bend. Try adding a few loop cuts where the knee should be. (control R)

Comment: How did you parent?  That is, which option did you pick from the parent menu?  It will probably be helpful if you added your blend file to your question. ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: @dunnowhattocallmyself perfect yo. Can you post as an answer so I can mark it correct to help you and others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to not having enough geometry. Go into edit mode, add a few loop cuts using Control R and put them where the knees should be